# How do I appropriately use Tinymce 4.1.9 with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have downloaded Tinymce 4.1.9 and I have used the example code found on the [demo page](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_version.php) but it did not initialize Tinymce I guess because on the version 4.1.9 there is **no file named tiny_mce.js** .

I have searched and found [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434388/how-do-i-use-tinymce-jquery-package-and-what-is-the-difference-with-tinymce-jque) and I have done this

```
<script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('textarea').html('<p>some dynamic content</p>').tinymce({
   theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
})


</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

That too did not work, the WYSIWYG is not displaying. I get only a textarea with no WYSIWYG. I do not know what I am missing if I want to use tinymce with Jquery.

**How do I appropriately use Tinymce 4.1.9 with Jquery?**

Comment: So what's not working - tinyMCE, jQuery, both?

Comment: The WYSIWYG is not displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

JQuery

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    ...
   });
});
```

HTML

```
 <textarea id="content" name="content" class="tinymce" style="width:100%">
```

[Source](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_plugin.php)