# TinyMCE not defined

Tags: javascript, tinymce, text-editor

I don't know why but in console I have an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined`. Here is the file where I want to define TinyMCE

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce"

});
```

Here is the HTML part

```
  <!--TinyMCE -->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/plugins/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
                    <!--TinyMCE -->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/plugins/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"></script>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="category"></label>

                        <textarea class="tinymce"></textarea>

                    </div>
```

Knows anybody what can I do?

Comment: have you Added the tinyMCE Js file to your Html?

Comment: yes, I came with an edit

Comment: needs a bit more information. Where are you executing the code from?

Comment: The HTML part is in a folder named cars. I have views/cars/index.php. And the init code is in plugins/tinymce/

Answer (score 3):

The process for installing the jQuery plugin version of TinyMCE is here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/advanced-install/#jqueryinstall

In particular you need to load **both** TinyMCE's main JS file (`tinymce.min.js`) and the `jquery.tinymce.min.js` jQuery plugin in order for this to work.  For example:

```
<script src="/path/to/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using the jQuery Version of TinyMCE, so the way your initialising the editor in your example is not the correct way.

you can continue to use the jQuery version or you can use the other version.

**Normal Js file script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery Initialise**

```
$("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
   //tinyMCE Settings here
 })
```

here is a post about it. : 
[How do i use TinyMCE jQuery package and what is the difference with TinyMCE jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434388/how-do-i-use-tinymce-jquery-package-and-what-is-the-difference-with-tinymce-jque)

Comment: The error is solved, but the textarea is not changeing is not working the TinyMCE..

Comment: Could be a few things, check if your invoking the TinyMCE init when the page has loaded

Comment: I've solved the problem using quick instalation from tinymce.com